# Start Loop when input start from a PI and stop when input stops (python)

Tags: python, loops, delay

Python: I'm writing a system that needs the program to wait until an input from the GPIO board on a raspberry comes through then loop until the input stops? Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an acceptable question.

Answer (score 0):

The best way , imho, is to use the event_detected() function of the RPI.GPIO module.
Take a look at http://raspi.tv/2014/rpi-gpio-update-and-detecting-both-rising-and-falling-edges

The example program detects rising and falling edges on GPIO 25